# Conditional formatting by using the note in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, conditional-formatting

How can I use conditional formatting by using the note on a specific or many cells in Google Sheets? For example, I would like to set up conditional formatting to a specific cell and when I use a note on that cell it will automatically change the color.

Comment: not possible by without script

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script to export your note into some side cell and then use simple conditional formatting to check if that cell is empty

```
function NOTE(cell)
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getRange(cell)
   return range.getNote();
}
```

- **formula:** **`=NOTE("A1")`**
- **custom formula for conditional formatting:** **`=IF(D$1:D<>"", 1)`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The built-in conditional formatting feature of Google Sheets can't be used to directly format cells based on notes content but you could use and add-on or Google Apps Script to do a conditional formatting tool.

Example:

This function runs every time a cell/range is edited. If the cell/range has a note the cell/range background color will be set to green.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getNote()){
    e.range.setBackground('green');
  }
}
```

NOTE: The onEdit simple trigger isn't triggered by inserting a note. As an alternative of a simple trigger you could make a script that check all the sheets cells calling it from a custom menu, from the script editor, an image or custom dialog/sidepanel.